# Заданный порядок строк в SQL-запросе

Tags: sql, запрос

Упрощённо: есть таблица с двумя полями, одно из которых типа Boolean. Возможно ли средствами SQL осуществить в этой таблице сортировку 1-к-3 по этому Boolean полю, т.е., на одно значение `true` далее идут три значения `false`? Наглядно:

```
name            | is_human
================================
Jon Doe         | true
Stuart Avery    | false
Vincent Babb    | false
Peter Bailey    | false
Marcus Bemrose  | true
Catherine Bird  | false
Catherine Bonner| false
Jack Brosnan    | false
Dennis Brown    | true
...             | false
...             | ...
```

СУБД: Postgresql 9

Comment: Зависит от диалекта используемого sql-сервера. Если поддерживаются оконные функции, в частности row_number, то можно

Comment: Укажите конкретную СУБД, включая версию. А в принципе задача - из несложных.

Comment: А что делать, если в таблице только `FALSE` или только `TRUE`?

Comment: Нужно некоторое дополнительное условие, так как порядок сортировки получается неопределенным.

Comment: Если в выборке соотношение объектов будет 1 к 3, то можно. И нужно, чтоб база поддерживала ROW_NUMBER. Примерно так: 1) select на true с `row_number*3 - 2`. 2) select на false с `row_number + (row_number+2)/3`. 3) объединение из 1) и 2) `order by row_number`. Думаю, можно как-то оптимизировать данную конструкцию

Comment: СУБД: Postgresql 9, добавил в описание

Comment: @Ainar-G если переходить от данной абстракции к конкретной задаче, то там такая ситуация невозможна

Comment: @MikhailIonkin в самой выборке соотношение объектов необязательно 1:3. Но объектов с true точно меньше, чем объектов с false.

Comment: Если не обязательно, то непонятно, что делать с оставшимися строками. Для них можно нарушить порядок, или их просто не выводить?

Comment: @MikhailIonkin остальные просто выводим как есть, т.е. после того, как объекты с true закончатся, далее до самого конца будут идти объекты с false. В общем, благодаря вашим подсказкам задачу я решил, завтра оформлю в ответ.

Comment: @MikhailIonkin или, если хотите, оформите сами ваш комментарий выше про row_number в ответ, я приму его. Вы очень помогли.

Comment: Давайте лучше вы оформите: у меня сейчас не стоит Postgresql, а потому я могу ошибиться при написании запроса -- с первого раза не всегда работает